# Loop through all cells, check if cell value is X then copy cells to different location

Tags: excel, vba

I have a CSV file with a single column and a billion rows of text. There is a lot of filler, fluff and unnecessary text in those rows, but also a repeating pattern that I want to copy to another sheet.

The CSV looks something like this:

| Column A |
| --- |
| Fluff |
| Above Value |
| Filter Value |
| Below Value |
| Fluff |

I need to check for a specific string in the 'Filter Value' cell, and if there is a match populate a table in a different sheet with the Filter Value, Above Value and Below Value, looking like this:

| Filter Values | Above Values | Below Values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FValue 1 | AValue 1 | BValue1 |
| FValue 2 | AValue 2 | BValue2 |
| ... | ... | ... |

The code looks like this. It is not putting the Above / Below values into the proper positions:

```
Sub CopyRecords()

Dim FilterCol As Range
Dim Filter As Range
Dim PasteCell As Range
Dim PasteCellAbove As Range
Dim PasteCellBelow As Range

' Clear Destination table for testing
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A2:C999").Clear

Set FilterCol = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A999")

For Each Filter In FilterCol

    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A2") = "" Then
        Set PasteCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A2")
        Set PasteCellAbove = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("B2")
        Set PasteCellBelow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("C2")
    Else
        Set PasteCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
        Set PasteCellAbove = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
        Set PasteCellBelow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("C1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    End If

    If Left(Filter, 5) = "Testo" Then
        Range(Filter.End(xlToLeft), Filter.End(xlToRight)).Copy PasteCell
        Range(Filter.Offset(1, 0), Filter.Offset(0, 0)).Copy PasteCellAbove
        Range(Filter.Offset(-1, 0), Filter.Offset(0, 0)).Copy PasteCellBelow
    End If
Next Filter
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe show a little more sample data which is closer to your *actual* data, or share the exact rules you want to use?  Are you saying that any cell value beginning with "Testo" should trigger reading the preceding and following values and adding them to the table?

Comment: It's indeed just a giant CSV file comprised of hundreds of form Emails. Every mail has a bunch of free space, free text elements and pointless information, but also these 3 set lines that are basically name, email and optin - the email line being the only one that's always filled. I want to parse the entire file for every line that reads 'email:' (I used Testo in the above example' and copy the email, the info above and below to a new table.

Comment: This sounds like a pivot. If that's not the solution, please describe you issue better. For instance, I see FValue 1 and FValue 2 in your after, but I don't see FValue 1 and FValue 2 in your before.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/e1da61ca724fd200c916488c3b9e6adf - this is what my data looks like. Tons of rows with all kinds of random data, the only constant inputs being Above, Testo and Below. There's never an entry where Testo is empty, which is why I wanna filter by Testo - Above and Below on the other hand can be empty. From this endless data column I need to extract ever distinct Testo cell and the corresponding Above and Below values (if those cells are empty then I need to pass over an empty cell into the destination table - looking like this: https://gyazo.com/9db628720c3064965a01e388971e2f2c)

Answer (score 0):

Try this - wherever possible it's much faster to work with arrays of data.

```vb
Sub CopyRecords()

    Dim data, r As Long, rwOut As Range, v
    
    'get all data as an array
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A" & _
                   .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
    End With
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)        'reporting sheet
        .Range("A2:C999").Clear        'clear destination table
        Set rwOut = .Range("A2:C2")    'first row of output
    End With
    
    For r = 2 To UBound(data, 1) - 1
        v = Trim(data(r, 1))
        If v Like "*email:*" Then
            rwOut.Value = Array(v, data(r - 1, 1), data(r + 1, 1)) 'write values
            Set rwOut = rwOut.Offset(1, 0)                         'next row down
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Executing this code doesn't actually do anything other than clearing the destination table, despite several cells like "email:" existing in sheet 1.

Comment: sorry missed the `*` wildcards from the `Like`

Answer (score 0):

If you really have a billion rows in your input file, I don't think you will want to open that in an Excel sheet in order to process it.
Here is a solution that opens a TextStream object and reads the source file line by line rather than reading it all into memory.
It dumps the output into a new worksheet in the Excel file, but depending on how large your output is, I wonder if you ultimately might want to write that out to a CSV file instead.

Anyway, here is a potential solution.  Note that I didn't do any parsing of the "Before" and "After" lines.

```
Option Explicit


Public Sub extractData()
    Const sourceName As String = "c:\apps\excel\so demo\input.csv" 'change this as necessary
    Const maxOutputRecs As Long = 10000000
    
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim ts As Scripting.TextStream
    Dim before, after, cLine As String
    Dim n, i As Long
    Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    
    
    Dim data() As Variant
    ReDim data(1 To maxOutputRecs, 1 To 3)
    
    'Add header line to output array
    data(1, 1) = "Testo"
    data(1, 2) = "Before"
    data(1, 3) = "After"
    
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(Filename:=sourceName, IOMode:=ForReading, Create:=False)

    i = 0
    n = 0
    cLine = ""
    'read through source file line by line
    Do While Not ts.AtEndOfStream
        i = i + 1
        before = cLine
        cLine = ts.ReadLine
        If VBA.Left(cLine, 5) = "Testo" Then
            n = n + 1
            after = ts.ReadLine
            data(n + 1, 1) = cLine
            data(n + 1, 2) = before
            data(n + 1, 3) = after
            cLine = after
        End If
        
        If n + 1 = maxOutputRecs Then
            'end loop - may want to throw an error or write to a log file or do something else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    
    ts.Close
    
    data = redim2DArrayRows(data, n + 1, 3)
    
    'create a new worksheet for the output
    Set xlSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    xlSheet.Name = "output"
    'define the output range in the worksheet based on array size
    Set rng = xlSheet.Range( _
        xlSheet.Cells(1, 1), _
        xlSheet.Cells(UBound(data, 1), UBound(data, 2)) _
        )
    'Write data out to sheet
    rng.Value = data
    
    
End Sub



Public Function redim2DArrayRows(ByRef sourceArray() As Variant, ByVal rowBound As Long, ByVal colBound As Long) As Variant()
    Dim newArr() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    
    ReDim newArr(LBound(sourceArray, 1) To rowBound, LBound(sourceArray, 2) To colBound)
    For i = LBound(newArr, 1) To UBound(newArr, 1)
        For j = LBound(newArr, 2) To UBound(newArr, 2)
            newArr(i, j) = sourceArray(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
    redim2DArrayRows = newArr
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

### Extract Data Using `FindNext`

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExtractData()
    Const ProcTitle As String = "Extract Data"
    
    Const sCriteria As String = "Testo*" ' begins with ("*Testo*" contains)
    Const cCount As Long = 3 ' don't change: it's the same for source and dest.
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Source
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    Dim srg As Range
    ' Either static...
    Set srg = sws.Range("A2:A999") ' no cell above 'A1'
    ' ... or dynamic:
    'Set srg = sws.Range("A2", sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    
    Dim sCell As Range
    Set sCell = srg.Find(sCriteria, srg.Cells(srg.Rows.Count), xlValues, xlPart)
    If sCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim FirstAddress As String: FirstAddress = sCell.Address
    Dim sTemp As Variant: ReDim sTemp(1 To cCount)
    
    ' Destination
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(2)
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dws.Range("A2")
    Dim dColl As Collection: Set dColl = New Collection
    
    
    ' Write the 3 values to the Temp array and add the array to the collection.
    Do
        ' Modify here, if you don't need the complete cell contents.
        ' Cell
        sTemp(1) = sCell.Value
        ' Above
        sTemp(2) = sCell.Offset(-1).Value
        ' Below
        sTemp(3) = sCell.Offset(1).Value
        
        dColl.Add sTemp
        Set sCell = srg.FindNext(sCell)
    
    Loop Until sCell.Address = FirstAddress
    
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = dColl.Count
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To cCount)
    
    Dim Item As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    
    ' Loop over the arrays in the collection and write the elements
    ' of each array to a row of the Destination array.
    For Each Item In dColl
        r = r + 1
        For c = 1 To cCount
            dData(r, c) = Item(c)
        Next c
    Next Item
    
    ' Write the values of the Destination array to the Destination range.
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dCell.Resize(drCount, cCount)
    drg.Value = dData
    
    ' Clear the range below the Destination range.
    Dim dcrg As Range: Set dcrg = drg.Resize( _
        dws.Rows.Count - drg.Row - drCount + 1).Offset(drCount)
    dcrg.Clear
    'Debug.Print drg.Address(0, 0), dcrg.Address(0, 0)
    
    MsgBox "Done.", vbInformation, ProcTitle

End Sub
```